# What does it mean to create an object using: id <class> instanceName?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I saw some code on the apple website that goes like this

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = ...
```

How is this different to the following?

```
NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo *sectionInfo = ...
```

I'm not so interested in NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo itself, but rather the way it's declared.

Thanks a bunch!
Tristan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` is a protocol. id is a way of declaring a generic object, and `id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>` declares a generic object that must adhere to the `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` protocol.

Comment: So to be more explicit: `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo *sectionInfo` would not be a valid declaration, because a protocol is not a type.

Comment: mostly correct. a protocol is not a class (not "not a type"). you can't instantiate it. you can implement it, but not instantiate.

Answer (score 3):

That syntax is used to indicate that the object being referenced conforms to a specific protocol. See [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html) on this aspect of Objective-C, specifically the section "Conforming to a Protocol" and following.